# Expander View in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have used an expander view in my windows app. It contains sublistItems which could be one or many.

For example, if the expander list headers are `1, 2, 3`, then the sublistItems for 1 is `"a","b","c"`.
I have to get the index of the subitem (ex: "a", "b", or "c") when clicked.

Comment: What code have you written so far to try to help you solve the problem?  It may be helpful to post this code so that others can help you to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

you can creat a special command in your `C#` program and use `EventToCommand` and add an `eventtrigger` in `XAML`.
For more information visit this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx